# 3D animations for React Native Navigator scenes?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to do 3d transitions, like cube transitions as described here?
https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React native doesn't support 3D transitions, but you can use [React Native OpenGL library](https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react-native)

Comment: Looks very good, have to find now how to do own animation from one navigation 'scene' to another, seems no documentation about React Native navigation customisation.